# Enums as Keys for Types ... should this be a record. Why?

Tags: typescript

okay I've gone and done something I think is helpful, but now I'm wondering if I **should have just used a Record Type or even just a class?**

---

#### set-up

This is the crux of it.  I'm defining a type that is using an enum as its keys.  Whenif I expand upon the enum both enum and type ~benefit~ are affected.

```
enum Macros {
    fat = 'fat',
    protein = 'protein',
    carbohydrates = 'carbohydrates',
    calories = 'calories'    
}

type NutritionMacrosFields = { 
   [key in Macros] : number 
}

interface Food extends NutritionMacrosFields  {    
    amount: number,
   readonly baseServing : number
}
```

#### Another way this is helpful

is I can do this:

```
function updateMacros( f: Food, increase : number ){
    for( let m in Macros){
        let _m = m as Macros;
        f[_m] = Math.ceil(f[_m] * increase);
    }
```

##### [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFsHsBMFcBsCmANAdAFwM4FgBQiA7WcUAWQEMBjAJ0k1AG89QXQAzc9UAXlAHIO6PgBpmrAA610iAJYEe-SZGlyRYlpXLUARpAAWAT2jVOierz6ad+oyemY1uVqE3xI1GWYWXybj2b5nPABfPDx0A3FEUAA5WHQPdBlIAgoaOgAxT3hoc0ZQdQBtAGtEA1A5MipaTABdUAAuUCJwbURqAtxQ3Dw5aWoOSmiMyBhQRAAPaQJc2PjE5NTqzOzZ-NZ1UHIoWAJ0Jpa26lEnFmpEcmgU+HLtckxEAGV2gDc5AHNG5uIjkLDcECTcTuLi8BhpGrCEYwbrAABUCMRSORKLhoDhwDwIAq4GB1C44OWmCho2gwXYtBIfFQwGQfH+bF2lCSKVA70Q6Gh0AAFAQZA04gkZCylulMFlEDliVsdnsvod2gBKL5chhBU5nDmwajyADy2gAVohmah7pgZO8CNzGMFhM0ZHa1ZtnHcHs9qG8CJ8mgBGAAMftAJ2czm2kF2XCaYYjnRDrGCioA3H8erhGQRmYsXHpyF7EABBWXoa1sUkq0l26Nyg4-dqgZVMDWgJBcAD6VdB7FJpqLidjrFLMB74blvA7fc2sHE0FMELoJYrXaHHdAYHbRfrya6DKZItAU5n0jnmBLTS5drkNAuD3ltY6isbzlL1GtLYgFXkx4fztYb9bJF4Eh7iqMUtzjFg2EKf96l4Ch0D0VAhhkeBuUg6D0Q-K97kQJNNm6WFUUIxF0UxXBKBSTBICQRCkC0blcLIiiqMQVA3HeXlEAAd1AAARUx6MVPByIITAuHAAwAGkOUgLkFHZTlSW5J0m0EL5-TtFgQHAWBRPGCYZFEzYrF0QxjFMegmj9O0tJ0rhJgM9BNiUFR5CaABmDSbN0+zDKbVx3E8CzQH9AAmVdgG07z9N85xASmExHnQWA2DYNTA2xAhlC2TBzUtchtCQEI7X9QMGKEnM80LEdiwgSTpPPYKQtKrdhMo6i2OtPhxKk9AZNJERap6vqYEE1MsQiureq5VBXSeV4PgUABWAM+xAZCkHeXxQHOS5rgMf4gA)

Answer (score -1):

You can't actually use an Enum as a key for a record. The keys in `NutritionMacrosFields` do not remain Enum members. They are just strings with the same value as the Enum members since you've extracted values from the Enum.

In this case you may be better off using a union like

```
type Nurtition = 'fat' | 'protein' | 'carbohydrates' | 'calories'

type NutritionMacrosFields = { 
   [key in Nurtition] : number 
}
```

To really benefit from the Enum you'd want to use it as a value for a record.

```
Enum Diet {
  Palio = 'palio',
  Keto = 'keto'
}

const banana = {
   dietType: Diet.Keto
}
```